# Devexpress Datagrid and Xamarin.Forms component in the same View

Tags: xamarin.forms, devexpress

Can i have xamarin.forms component and Devexpress DataGrid in same View. I tried but only one shows.
Example:

````
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Enter Here" ></Entry>
            <DatePicker  FontSize="Large"></DatePicker>
            <Button Text="Search"></Button> 
<dxg:DataGridView  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" RowHeight="90">
                <dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
                    <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Name" IsReadOnly="true">
                        <dxg:TextColumn.Width>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="200" Phone="120" />
                        </dxg:TextColumn.Width>
                    </dxg:TextColumn>

                </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
            </dxg:DataGridView>
</Stack>```
````

Comment: It may be that DevExpress doesn't play well with other components.  It also may be that the component needs initialized, and you did not initialize.  In either case, most of those libraries come with support.  Have you asked them?

Comment: @Vasko,About adding DataGrid in Xamarin.forms, you can take a look the following article:https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400558/xamarin-forms/data-grid/add-grid-to-solution

Comment: **I find a solution. You can add Xamarin.Forms.Grid , Define rows and combine all types of elements in it.**

Comment: @Vasko, Glad to hear that you have found solution, please post one answer reply and mark your reply as answer, thanks.